# Snowflake-Internal Stage data load error: How to load "\" character

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In a file, few of the rows have \ in a column value for example, i have rows in below format.

1. 101,Path1,Z:\VMC\PSPS,abc
2. 102,Path5,C:\wintm\PSPS,abc

I was wondering how to load \ character

```
COPY INTO TEST_TABLE from @database.schema.stage_name FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE = CSV FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\"' SKIP_HEADER = 1 );
```

is there any thing that i can mention the file_format line?

Comment: Yes, you can escape it using any escape character you specify or use the default backslashes.  See ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD or ESCAPE options: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Comment: Just wondering why you have a \ in your FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY parameter?

Comment: I tried both ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\\' or ESCAPE = '\\'..i stil get the same error "End of record reached while expected to parse column"

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need any of that. What happens if you just use: FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE = CSV SKIP_HEADER = 1 ) ?

Comment: i tried using just FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE = CSV SKIP_HEADER = 1 ), but it didn't work. Got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Are you still getting this error? I just tried to recreate it by creating a CSV based off your sample data and a test table. I loaded the CSV into an internal stage and then ran your COPY command. It worked for me. Please see the screenshot below.

[image: Data loaded into Snowflake table]

Could you provide more details on the error you are facing? Perhaps there was something off with your table definition.